# Как подключиться к tor используя selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

Хочу подключиться к тору через Tor Browser, когда сам открываю браузер и нажимаю подключиться, то подключается довольно быстро, но если запустить веб драйвер, то загрузка будет бесконечная. Какие настройки нужно установить перед открытием?

```
public static FirefoxDriver initializeDriver() {
    String torPath = "E:\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe";
    String profilePath = "E:\\Tor 
    Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default";

    File torProfileDir = new File(profilePath);
    FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(torPath));
    FirefoxProfile torProfile = new FirefoxProfile(torProfileDir);

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setBinary(binary);
    options.setProfile(torProfile);
    options.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS,options);

    return new FirefoxDriver(options);
}
```

[image: Бесконечная загрузка]